# Displaying camel cased words as such with underscores in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, emacs, camelcasing

To me, reading long camel cased words can sometimes be a bit frustrating. For example:

```
aReallyLongCamelCasedMethodNameWhichIsTooSelfDescribing
```

Now, look at this version:

```
a_Really_Long_Camel_Cased_Method_Name_Which_Is_Too_Self_Describing
```

Which version is easier on your eyes? The second one is for mine.

While using Emacs, I stumbled upon a nice minor mode called [glasses mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GlassesMode).

Since I'm working primarily with Java, I'm an Eclipse user and I wonder if there is some way to display camel cased words with underscores?

Note that I'm not asking for a way to actually convert camel cased words as described, I'm just looking for a mechanism that works like Emacs' glasses mode in Eclipse.

A regexp to actually do the conversion can be found by googling "Convert camelCase to underscores".

Comment: I like to follow conventions because a high % of coding is maintenance which is generally not done by the person who wrote the code. The Java convention is to NOT use "_".

Comment: IHaveToAdmitThatIStronglyAgreeWithYouOnHowUnnaturalItIsToReadWordsWithNoSpacesInBetweenThemInEnglish. NoticeAlsoTheHorroribleProblemSomeFontsHaveInThatYouCannotTellInSomeCasesWhatIsOneLetterAndWhatIsAnother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find any existing Eclipse plugins, then I would consider writing your own editor extension.

Comment: It's obvious, but it seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Emacs as your Java IDE?  I really like Eclipse and the move sounds painful to me too.  However, I bump into more and more people that are actually doing it.  Just type "emacs ide java" into google.

It's definitely not a move for everyone, but if you know Emacs fairly well it might be a better option than trying to convert emacs features into Eclipse.

Comment: I've tried JDEE, but it still lacks the polish of "dedicated" Java IDEs. Since I'm working primarily in enterprisey Java with tons of frameworks and Eclipse plugins for them, I'm afraid productivity would suffer in Emacs. But I'll try it one day and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't laid down your mouse and gone into retirement yet, there are now 2 solutions to this:

1. use emacs within Eclipse [with the emacs+ plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs) although I haven't established that you can use a `.emacs` init file to pre-program much of the cool emacs stuff emacs can do like your requirement
2. convert camel-case to underscored separated using [the AnyEdit plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to go back

Answer (score 0):

try to keep your method names descriptive "and" short. If you have really such method names, i would think about it twice before i code it and maybe it is better to use refactoring "extract method" to tile the functionallity, which you can not describe shortly,  into more than one method for a better design ;-) "increasing cohesion"

Comment: I tend to use short and descriptive method names. I asked the question because other peoples' code can contain such overlong method names that are a pain to read even with IDE autocomplete.